# Converting to disjunctive normal form?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

The formula is: ¬((p → ¬q)∨(r∧¬s))

and what I've done so far is this :

¬((¬p∨¬q)∨(r∧¬s))

¬(¬p∨¬q)∧¬(r∧¬s)

(p∧q)∧(¬r∨s)

After this step I became really confused as to how to proceed. I'm not sure what to do. If anyone could provide help in explaining how to do it and if I did anything wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Are you after a form with only the connectives $\neg$ and $\vee$
in it? If so then after the first line you are almost there. It is enough
to convert $r\wedge\neg s$ into $\neg\left(\neg r\vee s\right)$.

Comment: I'm trying to get to a form where there is a disjunction between the terms. So there should be a ∨ between them. But the terms in the brackets can be conjunctions

Comment: I didn't check your work. From the last formula just distribute $\phi$ over $\neg r\lor s$, where $\phi=p\land q$ and you'll get a disjunction of conjunctions of literals, i.e., a DNF.

Comment: Use the distributive laws: $A\land(B\lor C) \Leftrightarrow (A\land B)\lor(A\land C)$.

Answer (score 1):

If $a$ stands for $\neg[p\rightarrow\neg q]$ then your second line gives
$$a\wedge\neg\left[r\wedge s\right]$$

You can write this as: $$a\wedge\left[\neg r\vee s\right]$$

Finally you can write this as: $$\left[a\wedge\neg r\right]\vee\left[a\wedge s\right]$$

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.